# javascript regular expression search a pattern A(xyz)

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to find all substrings from a string that starting with a given string following with a left bracket and then any legal literal and then the right bracket. For example, a string is abcd(xyz)efcd(opq), I want to a function that returns "cd(xyz)" and "cd(opq)". I wrote a regular expression, but it returns only cd( and cd(...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regex is:

```
/cd\([^\)]*\)/g
```

Try:

```
var reg = /cd\([^\)]*\)/g;
var match;
while(match = reg.exec(str))
{
  ...
}
```